# CSS: Floating Box With No Collision

Tags: html, css

Is it possible to have a floating box that doesn't collide with another element? Just like in this image: http://i.share.pho.to/76976921_o.png

I am planning to put my logo there but the ways that I know also moves the wrapper away. I would like to know if it is possible to make a literally floating box that overlaps another element.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the logo outside of your wrapper and give it absolute position.

```
img.logo{
  position:absolute;
  left:0px;
  top:0px;
}
```

You can perfect the positioning with the left and top values.
This way it will disappear when you scroll. If you want it to be visible always. use `position:fixed;` instead.